# Java DOM parser not parsing one line XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have this **one-line xml file** (without indents and new lines) as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.03" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.03 
camt.054.001.03.xsd">
    <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn><GrpHdr><MsgId>0000000006</MsgId>
<CreDtTm>2013-04-
    16T14:38:00</CreDtTm>
</GrpHdr>
</BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn></Document>
```

I am Using this java DOM parser program to parse and retrieve values

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class GetNodeValues {
    static String value = null;
    static ArrayList alist = null;

    /****************** GET XPATH FOR EACH TAG **************************************/

    public static String getXPath(Element elemnt) {
        String xpath = null;
        String curNode = elemnt.getNodeName();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(curNode);
        // al.add(parNode);
        while (!elemnt.getParentNode().getNodeName().equals("#document")) {
            al.add(elemnt.getParentNode().getNodeName());
            elemnt = (Element) elemnt.getParentNode();
        }

        for (int i = al.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            xpath = xpath + "/" + al.get(i);
        }
        return xpath.replaceAll("null", "");
    }

    /******************************************************************************************/

    /**************************** GET TAG NAMES AND VALUES ***********************/

    public static ArrayList getValues() {
        try {

            alist = new ArrayList();
            String xmlFile = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample2.xml";
            File file = new File(xmlFile);
            if (file.exists()) {

                // Create a factory
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                // Use the factory to create a builder
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                // Get a list of all elements in the document
                NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                    // Get element
                    Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
                    String nodnam = element.getNodeName();


                    if (element.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) // then it has
                                                                    // text
                    {
                        String val = element.getChildNodes().item(0)
                                .getNodeValue();
                        if (val.startsWith("\n")) { // Discarding pseudo nodes

                        } else {
                            value = nodnam + " > " + val + " > "
                                    + getXPath(element); // print node names and
                                                            // values
                            System.out.println(value);
                            alist.add(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print("File not found!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return alist;
    }

    /********************************************************************************************/

    /************************** MAIN METHOD **********************************************/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getValues());

    }
}
```

And its not printing any values. However if i edit the xml file and add indents and new lines like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.03 camt.054.001.03.xsd">
    <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>0000000006</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2013-04-16T14:38:00</CreDtTm>
        </GrpHdr>
    </BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
</Document>
```

then i get output like below

```
MsgId > 0000000006 > /Document/BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/GrpHdr/MsgId
CreDtTm > 2013-04-16T14:38:00 > /Document/BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn/GrpHdr/CreDtTm
```

So the problem is i cant edit each and every xml files as the no. of files to process is huge. Am i missing something in java dom parser ? All i require is that the program should parse and print values for xml files which dont have indents and new lines....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by doing:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.exit(1);
}
```

You are hiding the exception, and not able to see the real issues.
Print the stack trace, at least, like:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1);
}
```

In this case the `var` from `String val = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();` can be null. So using the following fix should resolve this issue:

```
String val = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
if (val != null) {
   if (val.startsWith("\n")) { // Discarding pseudo nodes
   } else {
       value = nodnam + " > " + val + " > "
            + getXPath(element); // print node names and
                                // values
       System.out.println(value);
       alist.add(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, After adding e.printStackTrace() i was getting NullPointerException. Then I changed the code as you suggested and now its working as it should. Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the actual problem that caused the NPE, I think that there are 3 distinct problems with your code at this point:

```
  } catch (Exception e) {
     System.exit(1);
  }
```

The first problem (as noted by @dan) is that you are not printing a stack trace.

The second problem is that you are catching `Exception`.  This is a bad idea in most situations because you end up catching all sorts of unexpected exceptions ... in addition to any that you might be expecting.  It is far better to catch only the exceptions that you expect and can deal with at that point.  The rest of them should be allowed to propagate.

The third problem is that you are calling `System.exit` in what appears to be a utility method.  That is a bad idea for a couple of reasons:

- Bailing out in a method is going to make that method difficult to use in other contexts ... where bailing out is the wrong thing to do.
- Any method that calls System.exit is going to be tricky to unit test.  If you don't take steps to avoid it (e.g. using a mocking framework that can "mock" that call) that method is going cause the JVM running the unit tests to stop ... immediately.

In my opinion, the correct way to write that code would be to:

1. add any necessary `throws` clauses to the `getValues()` method declaration, and
2. put the `try ... catch` in the `main` method ... with some code to output or log the exception stacktrace of course.